# Buenas practicas en DTO

Tags: java, clase

mas que nada quiero hacer una consulta sobre los mapeos usando DTOs.
Quería saber si el siguiente proceso es considerado una mala practica o hay una manera mas optima de mapear un objeto, ya que con getter y setter se me hace una vuelta un poco mas larga, no es que eso este mal, si no que pensé que esto podría ser mas rápido, mas aun cuando se necesita mapear el mismo objeto en distintos lugares.

#### Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
@Data
public class Cliente{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_cliente")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idCliente;
    private String nombreCliente;
```

#### DTO

```
import entities.Cliente;

@Data
public class ClienteDTO{
    private Long idCliente;
    private String nombreCliente;
    private Boolean estado;

  public ClienteDTO(Cliente cliente) {
        this.idCliente= cliente.getIdCliente();
        this.nombreCliente= cliente.getNombreCliente();
        this.estado= cliente.getEstado();
  }
}
```

#### Service

```
public List<ClienteDTO> findByEstado(Boolean estado){

       /* 
         return calendarTasksRepository.findByEstado(estado).stream()
               .map(x-> new ClienteDTO(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
       */

        return calendarTasksRepository.findByEstado(estado).stream()
               .map(CalendarTasksDTO::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

#### Repository

```
@Repository
public interface CalendarTasksRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Long> {

   List<Cliente> findByEstado(Boolean estado);
}
```

gracias de antemano.

Comment: La forma de mapear está bien. Cuando estás mapeando un modelo a un DTO es muy cómodo hacerlo de esa manera . Ahora, considera que si vas a recibir de parte del usuario un `ClienteDTO`  debes incluir los setters para que spring pueda hacer el binding. Alternativamente checa [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) cuando tengas muchas entidades y quieras realizar el mapeo automático.

Comment: muchas gracias, revisare esa documentación. Para complementar, @Data es una funcion de Lombok que te permite generar los get a set de manera automática.

Comment: Yo te recomendaría no utilizar @Data en los Dtos. Checa esta pregunta, precisamente habla de ello https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51820133/using-data-annotation-on-java-dto-class.

Comment: gracias, lo tendré en consideración